# Audio stream from secondary computer

Tags: windows, audio, streaming, remote-access, audio-streaming

**What is the simplest/best way to get the audio from my desktop to output on my laptop?**

1. I have two computers at work, a laptop and a desktop.
2. While I'm at work I have to use both machines simultaneously.
3. I have input director (similar to synergy) installed on my laptop to control my desktop
4. Frequently, I'll have to open links on my desktop that have audio (or I find out after I click the link that it is a video or something).
5. I use headphones connected to my laptop - speakers or a second set of headphones isnt an option.

*note that streaming services like icecast have multi-second delays even in lan environments*

Answer (score 1):

If you have a line input on your laptop, you could just feed it with the audio signal from your desktop system and set the mixer appropriately. If not, the other direction and connecting the headphones to the desktop system might be acceptable.

Comment: Sometimes low-tech is the way to go :)

Comment: Yep, and you can barely beat the latency of this solution. Also no load on CPU or network and it works independently of OS and software :) The only downside I see is: You might need to spend one or two bucks for a cable.

Answer (score 0):

I found some software that works very well:

- [VaCard Streamer](http://www.barix.com/downloads/Software_tools/221/)
- [Virtual Audio Card (VACard)](http://www.barix.com/downloads/file/Virtual_Audio_Card_VACard_2b1_ZIP/9481/221)

The latency is great and it's super easy to set up. As it is, I have to plug in a lot of cables to my laptop, so I really prefer a software solution.

Comment: fyi, this software doesnt seem to be actively developed anymore

Comment: Links bit rotted.